# set the waiting time for a command to all users: setTimeout

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I set a wait time for the !corona command it works fine but I want to remove a wait time when the user enters the country abbreviation incorrectly. All my codes are as below.

In short, when a wrong country command is entered, for example "!corona US" should query a new one without waiting time.

actually this works fine but two people can start this command at the same time. once the command is entered I want a waiting period for everyone. this only gives a wait time for the member who uses it

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const hereTimeOut = new Set();

exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if (hereTimeOut.has(message.author.id)) {

        const waitsetTimeOut = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        waitsetTimeOut.setColor(0x00AE86)
        waitsetTimeOut.setTimestamp()
        waitsetTimeOut.setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
        waitsetTimeOut.setTitle("[wait a while]")
        waitsetTimeOut.setDescription('please wait 1 minute')
        return message.channel.sendEmbed(waitsetTimeOut);
    }else {


    let country = args.slice(0).join(' ');

    if(!country){

        fetch("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/").then(res => res.json()).then(json => {

            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
                embed.addField("**= Total Number of Cases =**",`**`+ json.confirmed['value'] +` person**`)
                embed.addField("**= Number of Healing Cases =**",`**`+ json.recovered['value'] +` person**`)
                embed.addField("**= Number of Cases Losing Life =**",`**`+ json.deaths['value'] +` person**`)
                embed.setColor(15962634)
                embed.setTitle('Worldwide COVID-19 Statistics')
            message.channel.send({embed: embed});

        });

    }else{

        fetch(`https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/${country}`).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {

                const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
                    embed.addField("**= Total Number of Cases =**",`**`+ json.confirmed['value'] +` person**`)
                    embed.addField("**= Number of Healing Cases =**",`**`+ json.recovered['value'] +` person**`)
                    embed.addField("**= Number of Cases Losing Life =**",`**`+ json.deaths['value'] +` person**`)
                    embed.setColor(15962634)
                    embed.setTitle(`COVID-19 Statistics (${country})`)
                message.channel.send({embed: embed});

        }).catch(() => {

            message.reply("I couldn't find the country you are looking for, be careful not to use Turkish letters when writing the country. You can also write country abbreviations (ex: TR, USA, AZ)");

        });

    }

    hereTimeOut.add(message.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          // Removes the user from the set after a minute
          hereTimeOut.delete(message.author.id);
        }, 60000);
    }

};

exports.conf = {
  enabled: true,
  guildOnly: true,
  aliases: ['corona'],
  permLevel: 0
};

exports.help = {
  name: "corona",
  description: "covid19",
  usage: "coronavirus"
};
```

part of the error it received when it used a wrong country command;

```js
.catch(() => {
    message.reply("I couldn't find the country you are looking for, be careful not to use Turkish letters when writing the country. You can also write country abbreviations (ex: TR, USA, AZ)");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to store whether the command is available to use or not, you can then edit it like this:

```js
// Setup
let isAvailable = true,
  cooldownMS = 5000; // in ms, this is 5 seconds

// When you're running the command:
if (isAvailable) {
  isAvailable = false
  setTimeout(() => {
    isAvailable = true
  }, cooldownMS)
  // Run your command ...
} else {
  // The command is still cooling down, send a message to the user to let them know
}
```